# Проверка текста на настроение

Tags: python, python-3.x, анализатор, лексический-анализатор

Хочу отображать в шапке группы ВК поздравление с новым годом от пользователей. Но хочу, чтобы там были только добрые пожелания/поздравления. Времени на обучения нейронной сети нет. 
Ищи API или библиотеку, которая справится с этим. Есть идеи?

Comment: Боюсь, что с достаточной точностью это невозможно, и даже люди не справятся. "Желаю россиянам, чтобы в новом году президентом оставался Путин" - это доброе пожелание или нет? :)

Comment: @andreymal ну, это да. Но должно же быть хоть что-то, чтобы отсеить явно негативные

Comment: связанный вопрос [Sentiment retriving from text (Russian)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/10211/43437)